# Why didn't Windows create a User_Data folder for a new profile?

Tags: windows, users, profile

Normally the User_Data folder is created automatically when the new user logs into their profile. Where/how can I check what's preventing this?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Windows are you using?
If Win7,8, or 10 it should be c:\users\%username%\appdata\
local\
locallow\
roaming\

The appdata folder is a hidden folder so it might be there. You just need to show hidden files.

Comment: Windows 7. I'm checking it from the server though, and she doesn't have a User_Data folder at all (I see everyone else's). Her desktop is just saving files locally.

Comment: Okay so are you talking about folder redirection or a home folder?

Comment: The user has a local home folder, but does not have a User_Data folder on the server, which contains the Desktop, Documents, AppData folders so that they can be accessed from any machine on the network. Normally this folder is created automatically when the user logs into their Windows profile for the first time but this time it was not. I'm not sure what kinds of things to even look for besides permissions. Thanks for your help, by the way!

Comment: With a HOME directory I don't believe anything is created automatically. It's more of just a remote folder. 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320043

A roaming profile on the other hand would have the desktop/appdata you are looking for.
A roaming profile is controlled in group policy for a domain.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649079.aspx

You have to make sure permissions on the server share are proper as well as the group policy settings correct in order to send the data to the right destination.